# How to create a button like New Mail in Outlook add-in?

Tags: outlook, vsto, add-in, outlook-addin, commandbar

Can anyone pls tell me how to create a button(in CommandBar) like 'New Mail' (with a dropdown list) in Outlook? 
When one clicks on the button it should do some action and when clicked on the down arrow mark, it should populate a list of items. I am in need of this very much.
If anyone know the answer pls let me know.

Thanks in advance!

-Pranav

Comment: Please have a look at my answer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7052233/outlook-2010-add-in-how-to-customize-from-to-cc-subject-pane/7054714#7054714

Answer (score 1):

Assuming **Outlook<2007**, you add a new button to the explorer/inspector via `CommandBars.Add("foo", Type:=msoControlDropdown)` and add entries to the drop-down via `myDropdown.Add("bar")`.
See also the reference for [CommandBarComboBox](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa432072.aspx).
You can't populate it on click though, you have to find other suitable events for that, e.g. `Explorer.SelectionChange`.

On **Outlook >= 2007** you need to customize the ribbon which is a bit more writing work. [Customizing the Ribbon in Outlook 2007](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb226712.aspx) is a good introduction into that.

To create a new mail item use `myOlApplication.CreateItem(olMailItem)` or `myMailFolder.Items.Add()`, set it up as needed and show it in an inspector via e.g. `myMailItem.Display()`.

Answer (score 1):

Sound like you are looking for a split button. Unfortunately the API does not expose that.
You can hack up a Popup under the button which is a poor attempt of a split button.